# É possível instalar o Android sem edição do fabricante?

Tags: android, linux, sistema-operacional

Olá, Se em uma situação hipotética, eu tiver como mudar o boot do meu celular, eu posso instalar o Android cru? Tipo, eu sei que os fabricantes mudam ele antes de instalar, mas sem essa edição ele funciona? Pq eu sei que quem faz a comunicação entre o hardware e software é o kernel linux.
E seguindo está lógica, poderei também instalar o ubuntu para celulares, afinal ele também usa o kernel linux

Comment: Você pode instalar a versão limpa sim. Basta ter a imagem e fazer a instalação. E acho sua pergunta *off-topic*

Comment: O importante é compilar os fontes para o celular correto, configurar o kernel corretamente, e utilizar os drivers certos. Tendo isso em mente, você pode inclusive modificar o Android para o seu gosto. Mas da um trabalho enorme fazer isso (experiência própria...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim.

Essas versões são geralmente chamadas de Android AOSP. Já existem versões do AOSP compiladas e prontas para instalar em vários modelos de aparelho.

Quanto ao Ubuntu, na teoria deve funcionar mas não tenho experiência para opinar sobre isso.